# Storing Index file in HDFS- Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr, solrcloud

I'm configuring Solr to store index data file in HDFS.

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -c -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.hdfs.home=hdfs://localhost:50070/solr
```

when I tried to open solr's url and I got error as "SolrCore Initialization Failures", Problem creating directory.

[image: Screenshot of error.For reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port used seems wrong
`hdfs://localhost:50070/solr`

Try `hdfs://localhost:8020/solr` you can see the hdfs port in your core-site.xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this command as the 'solr' user, make sure 'solr' has permission on HDFS to write into the '/user/solr' direction. If not, you can change owner for that dir by using `hadoop fs -chown solr /user/solr` and make sure it has write permission (try this command: `hadoop fs -chmod 755 /user/solr`).

Comment: I don't have user as 'solr'. I'm working on default configuration only

Comment: So are you running Solr as 'root'? Whichever user you are running Solr as, make sure that user has permission to write to HDFS :)

Comment: User got permission to write into HDFS. I've copied some file manually for cross checking purpose